# How to run Eclipse 3.4.1 on MacOS 10.5.6?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am trying to run Eclipse 3.4.1 on MacOS 10.5.6?
I think I am using java 1.5 when I run eclipse:

$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ java -version
java version "1.5.0_16"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_16-b06-284)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_16-133, mixed mode, sharing)

And then I click eclipse icon.

In the Preferences->Java->Installed JREs, I did click 'JVM 1.6.0', since I needs to use 1.6 for my project.

But in the .log file, I am getting these errors, why there is class file bad version number? And how can I fix it?

```
!SESSION 2009-01-29 10:07:29.618 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20080911-1700
java.version=1.5.0_16
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=carbon, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/samuel/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws carbon -arch x86 -keyring /Users/samuel/
.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2009-01-29 10:07:42.947
!MESSAGE Failed to start com.android.ide.eclipse.editors
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.android.ide.eclipse.editors
.EditorsPlugin.start() of bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActiv
ator(BundleContextImpl.java:1028)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(Bund
leContextImpl.java:984)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(Bundl
eHost.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(Abstrac
tBundle.java:265)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$11.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class 
file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:675)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.
findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:316)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMo
nitor.loadAndParseRClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMo
nitor.projectOpenedWithWorkspace(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.ResourceMonitor.add
ProjectListener(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMo
nitor.setupMonitor(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.ResourceManager.set
up(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.EditorsPlugin.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(Bund
leContextImpl.java:1009)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActiv
ator(BundleContextImpl.java:1003)
        ... 4 more
Root exception:
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:675)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.ProjectClassLoader.
findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:316)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMo
nitor.loadAndParseRClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMo
nitor.projectOpenedWithWorkspace(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.ResourceMonitor.add
ProjectListener(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.CompiledResourcesMo
nitor.setupMonitor(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.resources.manager.ResourceManager.set
up(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.editors.EditorsPlugin.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(Bund
leContextImpl.java:1009)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActiv
ator(BundleContextImpl.java:1003)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(Bund
leContextImpl.java:984)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(Bundl
eHost.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(Abstrac
tBundle.java:265)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$11.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse on Mac OS X on Intels only works with JDK 5 (it's horrible). I always have to create two versions of my plugins.

However, it seems that the Android editor plugin that you're using was compiled against 1.6, so I'm not sure that there's a solution...

Comment: Thanks. But from the android document, it said 'JDK 5 or JDK 6' will work.

http://code.google.com/android/intro/installing.html

So I am confused.

Comment: not true! been using JDK 1.6 for a year now on my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
```

That error means that you're attempting to execute bytecode in a JRE that is older than the JDK you used to compile.  In your case, the version 5 JRE doesn't recognise the file magic added by the v6 JDK and quits before it hits bytecode it can't understand.

The solution to this is to either specify a target version for the compiler, or upgrade your JRE.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install java 6 on to your Mac if you want to 1.6 in your project.  You should be able to get java 6 here:

http://developer.apple.com/java/download/

Comment: Thanks. I have java 6 and java 5 on my Mac. But I think eclipse 3.4 needs java 5 to work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get Eclipse 3.5M5 to run with JDK 1.6.0 as its base VM with a slightly modified path from above:

> ./eclipse -vm
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0

Better, I was able to put it in the eclipse.ini file in /Applications/eclipse3.5/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS, so long as it went above the '-vmargs'. For example:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090128-1500.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.0.0.v20081125-1800
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vmargs
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the latest Galileo (Eclipse 3.5) milestone. It is not very stable, but it will run on Apple's JDK 1.6. Get it [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) (3.5M4 is the latest). Make sure you get the cocoa 64 bit version.

Start it with `-vm /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Commands/java`

Again, an early beta with all implications.

Comment: In the notes for 3.5M4 Cocoa it says "Eclipse does not currently run on (64-bit) Java 1.6."